# Having ip address check whether there is an interface in the system with such a network

Tags: python-2.7, ip-address

That's what happened to me:

```
>>> import os
>>> import re
>>> import ipaddress
>>> import netifaces

>>> ip = ipaddress.ip_address(u'192.168.2.112')

>>> def network_check(ip):
    x = netifaces.interfaces()
    for i in x:
        if i != 'lo':
             int = ipaddress.ip_interface(unicode(os.popen('ip addr show '+i).read().split("inet ")[1].split(" ")[0]))
             netw = int.network
             if ipaddress.ip_address(ip) in ipaddress.ip_network(netw):
                  return ip
             elif i:
                  i += i
             else:
                  return False
```

I had 2 questions:

1. How to add False to the output if the script did not find matches?
2. If several subnets are raised in one VLAN, how to make sure that it is checked not only by the first IP?

As an example output `ip addr show vlan1111:31`

```
    3: vlan1111@enp2s4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.0.111/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global vlan1111:0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 192.168.1.110/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global vlan1111:1
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 192.168.2.110/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global vlan1111:2
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 192.168.31.110/24 brd 192.168.31.255 scope global vlan1111:31
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::216:17ff:fef0:111b/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```